# C# BeginConnect callback is fired when not connected

Tags: c#, tcp

Using `tcpClient.BeginConnect` fires the async callback even though there is nothing for the client to connect to. I then get an exception about trying to `.GetStream()`.

```
    public void SetupSocket() {
        try {
            tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            tcpClient.BeginConnect(host, port, ConnectCallback, tcpClient);
            Console.WriteLine("begin connect");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
    }


    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result) {
        if (OnClientEvent != null)
            OnClientEvent(this, new ClientEventArgs(Action.Connect));

        Console.WriteLine("get stream");
        stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        Console.WriteLine("got stream");

        BeginReadAsync();
    }
```

Output `get stream` and then exception about trying to use GetStream on tcpClient before it is connected.

Comment: What alternative behavior for Timeout (and other connection exceptions) you suggest? Do you expect your callback to be never called even if something happens to the channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback passed to `BeginConnect` is called when the connect operation completes, regardless of whether it succeeds in connecting to the endpoint or fails.

In the `BeginConnect` callback, you need to call `EndConnect` with the `IAsyncResult` object you received, in order to complete the connect operation. The socket isn't usable until `EndConnect` is called; after that, if the socket successfully connected, you can proceed with reading and writing.