# Tcp.BeginConnect thinks it is connected, even if there is no server

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I am trying to make an aSync connection to a server using `TcpClient.BeginConnect`, but am encountering some difficulties. This is my first time using Tcp so please bear with me.

The connection itself works fine when the server is running, i can send and receive messages without problem. However when I stop the server and try to connect to it, `Tcp.BeginConnect` will pretend it is actually connected to a server without returning an error, until i try to actually send data which will obviously fail.

When i use `TcpClient.Connect()` instead it'll return `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.` when no connection is established after a few seconds, letting me know the connection failed.

Is there a way to get this same behaviour with `TcpClient.BeginConnect`? Or am I doing something wrong myself?

i looked around and found [C# BeginConnect callback is fired when not connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249239/c-sharp-beginconnect-callback-is-fired-when-not-connected) which is somewhat similair and the answer was that `EndConnect` had to be called in the callback before the socket becomes usuable, but i'm already doing that.

my code:

```
public static void OpenTcpASyncConnection()
{
    if (client == null)
    {
        client = new TcpClient();
        IAsyncResult connection = client.BeginConnect(serverIp, serverPort, new AsyncCallback(ASyncCallBack), client);
        bool succes = connection.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();//returns true
        if (!succes)
        {
            client.Close();
            client.EndConnect(connection);
            throw new Exception("TcpConnection::Failed to connect.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("TcpConnection::Connecting to {0} succeeded", serverIp);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("TcpConnection::Client already exists");
    }
}

public static void ASyncCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Debug.Log("Pre EndConnect");
    client.EndConnect(ar);
    Debug.Log("Post EndConnect");//this never gets called?
}
```

the boolean `succes` is true even if the server is offline (or does this always return true as long as the operation finishes?), thus i assume it thinks it is actually connected, and the `Debug.Log` after `client.EndConnect(ar)` never gets called. Not a single error gets returned.

In summary; Am I forgetting something/doing something wrong? or is this expected behaviour?

Edit: language is C# with the .net 3.5 framework. It is ment for a Unity application though i'm not inheriting from monobehaviour for this. If you require any additional information I will try to provide this.

Kind regards and thanks for your time,
Remy.

Comment: The main problem here is that client-side/server-side End... functions are called before Begin... functions on the other side.

You can know that server is offline only during the data send. So you need to ask server if it's online by sending some dummy messages every N-seconds.

Comment: Yes, all that the result of the `WaitOne` call tells you is that *the result is now available*. You really do need to call `EndConnect` to discover the *outcome* of the connection attempt.

Comment: I see, but does `EndConnect` not get called already in the Callback, and should thus give me the outcome?  Or am i missing something about how the callback works?

@MrgGek I will have to implement this aswel, thanks for the information.